# Getting a listbox item into several textboxes

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to make an item (or a string) in a listbox appear in 3 different textboxes. The string gets added to the listbox from user input. So far I've managed to get the three textboxes to display the entire string in every textbox. Although I want them to display different things. So I split the user input string into an array with three values but I can't seem to get it to display the relevant info in the three textboxes. I should also mention, the textboxes should only display their values whenever the listbox item is selected.

```
 private void firstContacts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //firstContacts is the listbox
        //txtFirstName, txtLastName and txtPhoneNumber are the 3 different textboxes

        if (firstContacts.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = firstContacts.GetItemText(firstContacts.SelectedItem);
            txtLastName.Text = firstContacts.SelectedItem.ToString();
            txtPhoneNumber.Text = firstContacts.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

private void btnSaveContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtNewContact.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                string[] delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                string[] stringArray = txtNewContact.Text.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);

                Contact person = new Contact(stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2]);
                firstContacts.Items.Add(person);


class Contact
    {
        public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber) //Constructor
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return LastName.TrimStart(' ') + " " + FirstName + PhoneNumber;
        }
        //Properties
        public string FirstName { get; private set; } 
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming that the different things are separated by a space (e.g. "firstname lastname 12345678") then this should work.

```
private void firstContacts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstContacts.Focused)
    {
        string[] words = firstContacts.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(" ".ToCharArray());
        if (words.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong format");
        }
        txtFirstName.Text = words[0];
        txtLastName.Text = words[1];
        txtPhoneNumber.Text = words[2];
    }
```

And to set the TextBoxes to blank when an item is deselected.

```
private void firstContacts_Unselected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFirstName.Text = "";
    txtLastName.Text = "";
    txtPhoneNumber.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I just had no real idea how to get there... Now I get the proper values added to the right textboxes - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to deal with string methods. The code below should help you to get each textbox the vlaue it need.

```
        string myString = "FirstName$Surname$PhoneNumber"; // listBox selected string value

        string myFirstName = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf("$")); // YOU CAN REPLACE THE $ CHARECTER WITH WIGHT SPACE ONE.
        myString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("$") + 1);

        string mySurname = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf("$"));
        myString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("$") + 1);

        string myPhoneNum = myString;

        Console.WriteLine("myFirstName:" + myFirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("mySurname:" + mySurname);
        Console.WriteLine("myPhoneNum:" + myPhoneNum);
```